How to disable Processor Performance Boost Mode in PopOS (Or similar distros)
So in Windows 10, I have to edit the registry to make this option available so I can disable it. Why do I need to do this? Because the processor will boost beyond the total power output of my laptop's power brick, causing the dedicated GPU to starve for power, leading to a BSOD, system hang or total automatic reboot. (This is a guess, it does cause massive issues when turned on however)
When I ran PopOS last year, I had similar issues. Either a gray or green screen of death. Sometimes the system would just hang. PopOS is the only distro that seems to handle NVidia Optimus correctly (The built-in software switch for the graphics).
So is there a way to disable this or it's equivalent in Linux? Or am I stuck to Win10?
Thanks!
The Gray Jedi

hey, the problem I have is that I have not worked with Windows in a very very long time. Can you explain (or link to) in technical terms what "Processor Performance Boost Mode" is? I'm guessing it's using what intel calls "Turbo Boost", i.e., if sensible, rather than running multiple cores at a sustainable high clock rate, run one at a clock rate that is thermally only possible for limited time (and throttle the other cores for the time being). But that conflicts with what you describe happens under Linux: Linux (as of now) doesn't have "screens of death", so if your screen suddenly … 1/2

https://prnt.sc/96A51z_F0JFl

shows flat color, that would indicate a very fundamental driver or hardware issue with the GPU – unlikely to be caused by underdimensioned power supply). 2/2

That screenshot tells me nothing about what that "Processor performance boost mode" does.

Posted a screenshot of the info it gives me. At first I assumed it was "Turbo Mode", but I had that disabled in Linux (And windows has it's own turbo disable), and neither worked as well as this option does. I have zero idea how or why it works.

Does this help?
https://prnt.sc/7VQiJxauQHzv

No that tells us nothing. Problem is that my Google-abilities fail me when it comes to searching for information of what Windows does; it's simply 100% spam, AI-generated platitudes and people telling each other about secret tricks they have no understanding of. So, really, can't tell you what the equivalent on Linux would be, not knowing what it does on Windows.

Ok, I found something interesting. Apparently it has to do with the processor's P-state-based behaviour. Still have no idea though, lol.

could you link to the source? I assume this is about intel processors, specifically? That's interesting; P-states handling used to be software (thus, operating system-controlled), but with later intel CPUs, you can program a power controller in the CPU to select what is reasonable within the bounds you give it). Maybe there's more about that in the source you've found? This sounds like your laptop vendor did a bad job at giving your laptop firmware, so that the CPU doesn't know the right properties of the hardware.

I'm doing some reading/searching now. I'm on a AMD cpu, so the intel fixes don't work on linux for me. I've already visited a few websites that I recognize from the last time I went down this rabbit hole. However, I'm seeing posts about a update 5-6mo ago to PopOS' system76-power that might actually fix the issue. Plus, PopOS runs on the AMD p-state regardless of CPU since they claim it is more efficient.

you said you found something. Link, please.

Ok, now I see the diverging issue I was having. The rabbit hole I went down last time was the processor's C-State, NOT the P-State. I was in the wrong state! Lol. Anyway, this may actually be a fix for when I switch back to PopOS once Microsoft starts charging Win10 users a monthly fee. Thanks for being a blackboard I could ping off of, it triggered a few ideas.

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/umjii9/how_to_permanently_disable_amdpstate/

https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/174df8x/disable_cpu_boosting/

Normally, I would be able to disable P and C States in the BIOS, but this is an ASUS laptop, and their BIOS is designed to be monkey friendly. AKA, as limited as possible, lol.

I'm not sure what "disabling P-states" would mean; these are simply the state that your CPU is in when it does work…

The P State, as far as I can tell, controls how much it can boost over it's default clock speed. And I have to assume as it is boosting as much as 70% over default, it has to be pulling way more power.

https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/archive/42.2/tuning/html/book.sle.tuning/cha.tuning.power.html#:~:text=While%20a%20processor%20operates%20(in,at%20which%20the%20processor%20runs.

this should be moved to a chat

I'm a new user, it wouldn't let me.
